# docker install nsenter , command not found

Tags: docker

while i use `jpetazzo/nsenter` to install `nsenter` to `"/usr/local/bin"`

but i can not find nsenter in "/usr/local/bin",and `"bash: nsenter: command not found"`

```
bash-3.2$ docker images
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu                             mengka              8eaa4ff06b53        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
fedora                             latest              834629358fe2        2 weeks ago         241.3 MB
jpetazzo/nsenter                   latest              6ed3da1d7fa6        7 weeks ago         367.7 MB



bash-3.2$ docker run -v /usr/local/bin:/target jpetazzo/nsenter
Installing nsenter to /target
Installing docker-enter to /target


bash-3.2$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                     COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
c0c5ce8f8059        jpetazzo/nsenter:latest                   "/bin/sh -c /install   8 seconds ago       Exited (0) 7 seconds ago                        adoring_colden      
171c2439b5c7        jpetazzo/nsenter:latest                   "/bin/sh -c /install   4 minutes ago       Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                        insane_pasteur      
07d6e341af00        jpetazzo/nsenter:latest                   "/bin/sh -c /install   11 minutes ago      Exited (0) 9 minutes ago                        stupefied_carson    
18cab084f4f6        mengka-image-time01:latest                "/bin/sh mengka.sh"    19 hours ago        Exited (0) 4 hours ago                          fervent_morse


bash-3.2$ nsenter
bash: nsenter: command not found
```

Comment: `which nsenter` displays what ?

Comment: After the same `docker run...`as you, I get nsenter in `/usr/local/bin/nsenter` and `nsenter --help`displays the nsenter help

Comment: Check permissions. Try second approach `docker run --rm jpetazzo/nsenter cat /nsenter > /tmp/nsenter && chmod +x /tmp/nsenter`

Comment: Maybe this explains it: http://www.tutorialbeginner.com/nsenter-to-enter-docker-container/

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't answer the question, but are you aware that Docker 1.3 introduced a new "exec" command?

- https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec
- http://blog.docker.com/2014/10/docker-1-3-signed-images-process-injection-security-options-mac-shared-directories/

Answer (score 0):

you should use
       docker run --name nsenter -it ubuntu:14.04
to enter a os like ubuntu ,or center os ,and you can

Answer (score -1):

```
docker run --rm jpetazzo/nsenter cat /nsenter > /tmp/nsenter && chmod +x /tmp/nsenter
```